# How to change the user profile property value for all users via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-profile-property

We have a bool: User profile property.

Is there a way to set the value of this field to 'false' for all users?

The user profile property exists only in the SharePoint and not in AD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can iterate through all user profiles and update them. The PowerShell script can look like this:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Office.Server"); 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$site=Get-SPSite "https://yourSitecCollection"
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;            

$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);            
$userProfile = $upm.GetUserProfile("myarlett@company.com");

foreach($userProfile in $upm)
{
  $userProfile["PropertyName"].Value = "Test Value";   
  $userProfile.Commit()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=TestOU,dc=domainController01,dc=com" | Set-ADUser -customProperty $true
```

OR

```
# Get all users in the SomeOU.
$AllUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ChangeMeOU,OU=UserAccounts,DC=DomainController01,DC=COM"
# Iterate the users and update the department and title attributes in AD.
foreach($oUser in $AllUsers)
{
    # Update properties.
    $oUser.department = "Finance"
    $oUser.title = "Analyst 1"   
    # Update the user data in AD using the Instance parameter of Set-ADUser.

    oUser.CustomProperty = "WhateverYouWantHere"
    Set-ADUser -Instance $oUser
}
```

Comment: This will only change the AD User but not the user profile in SharePoint.

Comment: true, Once user changed AD, they can run a synchronize in Central Admin to see the changes.

Comment: Well if the property exists in the Profile and Active Directory and if they are mapped then it might probably work yes. ;)

Comment: The user property exists only in the SharePoint and not in AD.

Answer (score 1):

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::Loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.Office.Server"); 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$site=Get-SPSite "http://site:8080"
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site;            

$upm = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);    
$profiles = $upm.GetEnumerator()        
foreach($userProfile in $profiles)
{
    write-host $userProfile["AccountName"]
    write-host $($userProfile["AboutMe"])
    write-host $($userProfile["Matricule"])
    write-host "Telephone :" $($userProfile["HomePhone"])
    $userProfile["AboutMe"].Value = "Matricule: "+ $userProfile["Matricule"].Value+",  Tel: "+     $userProfile["HomePhone"].Value;   
    $userProfile.Commit()
}
```

## This work well !

Comment: the code of "Anton Khritonenkov" miss $profiles = $upm.GetEnumerator() before foreach

Answer (score 0):

You can directly update the profile properties and if its for all users then you can loop through all web.users

$web=get-spweb -identity http://

$user=$web.EnsureUser("")

$user | fl     -- this will show the user id and pass that id to below script in GetitembyID method

$web=get-spweb -identity  http://

$list=$web.lists["user information list"]

$item=$list.GetItemById(6007)

$item["JobTitle"]=""

$item["Department"]=""

$item.Update()

$list.Update()

$web.Update()

Refer:-https://www.sharepointcollabs.com/2021/06/updating-sharepoint-userprofile.html